# Can't get out of an infinite loop

Tags: c, infinite-loop

I worked on a simple exercise where i have to ask some mathematical questions and the user need to respond using integer values and I did everything except for the part where when something else than an integer is used i get an infinite loop... I can stop it using a break but i want to be able to ask again the user to input a integer.

Here"s the code, (I use this website to test my code [https://repl.it/languages]) if I could get some insight on it it would be awesome ! Thanks !

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

char ft_op()
{
 srand(time(NULL));
 char lop[4] = "+-/*";
 int rop = rand() % 4;
 char op = lop[rop];

 return op;
 }

 int ft_result(int nb1, int nb2, char op)
  {
   int result = 0;

   if (op == '+')
    result = nb1 + nb2;
   else if (op == '-')
    result = nb1 - nb2;
   else if (op == '/')
    result = nb1 / nb2;
   else
    result = nb1 * nb2;

   return result;
  }

int main(void)
 {
srand(time(NULL));

int nb1;
int nb2;
char op;
int uresult;
int result;
int nbq = 1;
int grade = 0;

while (nbq < 11)
{
  nb1 = rand()%101;
  nb2 = rand()%101;
  op = ft_op();
  result = ft_result(nb1,nb2,op);

  printf("\nQuestion %d : Calculez %d %c %d = ",nbq, nb1, op, nb2);
  if (scanf("%d", &uresult) != 1)
  { 
   printf("\nErreur de saisie. Veuillez recommencer.\n");
   break;
  }
  else
    {
      nbq = nbq + 1;
      if (result == uresult)
      {
        grade = grade + 1;
        printf("\nBravo vous avez deviné juste !\n");
      }
      else
        printf("\nPas de chance, votre résultat est %d et le bon résultat %d\n",uresult, result);
    }
}
printf("\nVotre note finale est de %d/10", grade);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You are only incrementing nbq when scanf fails

Comment: what does your program print?

Comment: The nbq increment only when the scan is right and the program print the grade at the end, if you guess right or wrong, you go to the next question, depending on the answer you get a +1 grade or not until you get to the last question (10th) and I want to ask again when the scan fail.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to clear/absorb the input stream when the input is not a number.

```
int c   
while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
```

The loop above will keep taking a `char` from the input till it finds a new line or the EOF (End of file). It doesn't need to do anything with the input so there is no body block.

Replace `break;` with `continue;`

```
if (scanf("%d", &uresult) != 1) { 
   printf("\nErreur de saisie. Veuillez recommencer.\n");

   int c   
   while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);

   continue;
}
```

Comment: I'm writing here again, I'm new here so I don't know how it really works, but thanks for the answer I'll take a look at it !

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica yes, I forgot to remove it before posting. Thank you